# Sorting items when using StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using StaggeredGridView and it has 3 columns. Problem that I have occurs when I have 4 items in the list. In the first row everything is ok, but in the second row the 4th item goes below the item from the first row which has smallest height.

So for example when the third item from the first row (item that is in the third column)is the item with the smallest height, in the second row 4th item will be below third item from the first row (it will be in the third column).

What I would like to have is that the item from the second row always be on the first position in that row, no meter what size of the items from first row is.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: This reminded me of Pinterest and how they do it; isn't that what Staggered actually implies?

Comment: No it's not. After testing it, I saw that position of the item from the next row is based on the size of the items from the previous row